# using fromJSON in a function to capture URLs' data

Tags: r, function

I am trying to capture data that is in JSON format from an API and put it in a dataset, using the following code:

```
mynamegenderfunction <- function(x){
  print(x)
  mydata <- as.data.frame(fromJSON(x))
}
genderdata <- lapply(namelisttest, mynamegenderfunction)
```

It seems not to be working as I receive the

> Error: Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file.

Although when I use a single url

```
fromJSON("https://api.genderize.io/?name=Matt ")
```

works perfectly.
Any idea why?

Comment: Can you also show us what's in `namelisttest` ?

Comment: If it's a list of names, I'm guessing you need to construct the url inside your function using `x <- paste("https://api.genderize.io/?name=", x)` (or something similar)

Comment: > namelisttest
                          namelist[1:8, ]
1 https://api.genderize.io/?name=Ezy-Bike
2     https://api.genderize.io/?name=Matt
3     https://api.genderize.io/?name=Carl
4 https://api.genderize.io/?name=SageFlow
5     https://api.genderize.io/?name=John
6      https://api.genderize.io/?name=Blu
7   https://api.genderize.io/?name=Arthur
8      https://api.genderize.io/?name=Tek

Comment: I pasted my namelisttest above. It is all links that I created with paste. it is odd that it gives error...

Comment: Your data seems to be a column in a dataframe, judging from "namelist[1:8, ]". In which case, it's probably been turned into a factor.

Comment: You are right. It is a how I made it:     namelisttest <- as.data.frame(namelist[1:8,])
What would be the solution? It is a data.frame but each row is actually a factor

Comment: Turn it back into character with `as.character`.